# How to pass boolean from html to scss mixin in react project

Tags: reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

I don't know if this is possible with SCSS but I'm trying, how do I pass a react boolean variable of **true** to an **scss mixin**?

My React component,
Here I pass a variable from the react-html side to scss

```
type Props = {
  isGrey?: boolean;
  isOrange?: boolean;
};

export default function Button({ isGrey, isOrange }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="button" style={{ '--isGrey': true }} >
      {isGrey.toString()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Sass code,
Here I try to use the boolean passed from the React code in a mixin, but it doesn't work

```
@mixin button-style($isGrey: false) {
  // @error $isGrey; // this prints "--isGrey" on screen, I need it to print true 
  @if $isGrey == true {
    border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
  } @else {
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
}

.button {
  @include button-style($isGrey: --isGrey);
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm just oldskool, but I'd stay away from even attempting something like this and just stick with a classical way of changing the style of your elements, specifically something like a button.

I'd just have your base button style

```
.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Then make use of some additional classes to change the style based on the boolean.

```
.btn-primary {
  border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.btn-secondary {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Within your component then just append the additional class based on the boolean.

```
  return (
    <div className=`button ${isGrey ? 'btn-Primary' : 'btn-Secondary'}`>
      {isGrey.toString()}
    </div>
  );
```

It's cleaner and easier to read.